# Entropy of fermions and bosons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I'm struggling with solving this question:

Show that the entropy per particle ($\ S/N$) is only a function of $\mu /KT$ for an ideal gas of Fermions and Bosons.

Assume that the gas is not relativistic, with known fixed values of 
$\ V \  (volume)\  ,\ T \ (teperature)\ ,\  m \  (mass)\ ,\  N \ (number\  of\  particles) $.

You don't need to solve explicitly.

Can someone help me with this questions?

Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764899/226902

Answer (score 3):

The Hamiltonian of an ideal bose/fermion gas:
$$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{P}}{2m}$$
Then you can compute the great partition function:
$$Z = Tr \ {e^{-\beta(\hat{H}-\mu \hat{N})}}$$
and after that the grand potential:
$$\Omega = -kT\ln Z$$
When you have this you can easly compute the entropy with:
$$S=-(\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial T})_{V,\mu}$$
I hope this helps, there are intermediate steps but this is only an outline.
If you want more details I could recommend reading eather David Tong's [lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf) (a bit easier) or more advanced [Feynman's Statistical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201360764).